# How to speed up mysql select in database with highly redundant key values

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a very simple MYSQL database with only 3 columns but several millions of rows. 
Two of the colums (hid1, hid2) describe study objects (about 50,000 of them) and the third column (score) is the result of a comparison of hid1 with hid2. Thus, the number of rows is max(hid1)*max(hid2), which is quite a big number. Because the table has to be written only once and read many million times, I selected a MyISAM table (I hope this was a good idea). Initially, it was planned that I would retrieve 'score' for a given pair of hid1,hid2 but it turned out to be more convenient to retrieve all scores (and hid2) for a given hid1.

My table ("result") looks like this:

```
+-------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| hid1  | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| hid2  | mediumint(8) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| score | float                 | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and a typical query would be

```
select hid1,hid2,score from result where hid1=13531 into outfile "/tmp/ttt"
```

Here is the problem: The query just takes too long, at least sometimes. For some 'hid1' values, I get the result back in under a second. For other hid1 (particularly for big numbers), I have to wait for up to 40 sec. As I said, I have to run thousands of these queryies, so I am interested in speeding things up.

Let me reiterate: there are about 50,000 hits to the query, and I don't need them in any particular order. Am I doing something wrong here, or is a relational database like MySQL not up to this task?

What I already tried is to increase the key_buffer in /etc/mysql/my.conf
this appeared to help, but not much. The index on hid1 is a few GB, does the key_buffer have to be bigger than the index size to be effective?

Any hint would be appreciated.

---

Edit:  here is an example run with the corresponding 'explain' output:

```
select hid1,hid2,score from result where hid1=132885 into outfile "/tmp/ttt"
Query OK, 16465 rows affected (31.88 sec)
```

As you can see below, the index hid1_idx is actually being used:

```
mysql> explain select hid1,hid2,score from result where hid1=132885 into outfile "/tmp/ttt";
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | result | ref  | hid1_index    | hid1_index | 4       | const | 15456 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

What I do find puzzling is the fact that query with low numbers for hid1 always are much faster than those with high numbers. This is not what I would expect from using an index.

Comment: What does `explain` say? And as an answer to the side question - yes a noSQL DB should be far more performant at this task than MySQL, but 40+ seconds does seem suspicious. Is it also that slow when not writing to the `outfile` but just querying in phpMyAdmin or from other PHP code?

Comment: You should have selected InnoDB due to how it optimizes working data set (saves the hot copy in RAM which makes selects super fast). Second, no - noSQL wouldn't be "far more performant", that's just ignorant talk. Down to the bottom - NoSQLs and RDBMSs work with HDD/RAM, except that RDBMS does "more" so it utilizes more CPU. Using InnoDB and indexing `hid1` and `hid2` will give you sufficient performance, given the fact you set the variable `innodb_buffer_pool` to the amount that can hold the data+indexes.

Comment: I think I tried InnoDB but did not see any improvment (except that loading the database from a tsv file takes a couple of hours rather than 20 min for the MyISAM table.

Comment: You can't use MySQL out of the box for higher volume processing / storage. The default configs are made so it works on old computers. InnoDB requires tuning, which usually boils down to variable `innodb_buffer_pool` being set to 90% of your RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Two random suggestions, based on a query pattern that always involve equality filter on `hid1`:

1. Use InnoDB table instead and take advantage of a clustered index on `(hid1, hid2)`. That way all rows belonging to the same hid will be physically located together, and this **will** speed up retreival.
2. Hash-partition the table on hid1, with a suitable nr of partitions.

Comment: I had also thought of your 2nd suggestion, but after reading about these partitions, I got the impression that this is only meant for splitting a database into separate files (and that 50,000 partitions would be an unusual thing to do). I will try your 1st suggestion.

Comment: @user900889, hash partitioning will work even if you use a smaller number of partitions. It won't be one partition per value, since multiple hid1 will map to the same physical partitition. If you have 5 million rows evenly distributed across 500 partitions, each partition (physical table) will contain only 10, 000 rows. Even with a full table scan, it will only take a second or so (provided that you include an equality predicate on hd1).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to optimize a query like that, would be to use an index. A simple thing like

```
alter table results add index(hid1)
```

would improve the query you sent. Even more, if you want to search by both fields at once, you can use both fields in the index.

```
alter table results add index(hid1, hid2)
```

That way, MySQL can access results in a very organized way, and find the information you want.

If you run an explain on the first query, you might see something like

```
| select_type | table  | type|possible_keys| rows   |Extra
| SIMPLE      | results| ALL |             | 7765605| Using where
```

After adding the index, you should see

```
| select_type | table  | type|possible_keys| rows   |Extra
| SIMPLE      | results| ref |hid1         | 2816304|
```

Which is telling you, in the first case, that it needs to check **ALL** the rows, and in the second case, that it can find the information using a **ref**

Comment: I already have an index on hid1 (see above). Without the index, it would be even slower.

Comment: How is that index defined?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the combination of hid1 and hid2 is unique, you should consider making that your primary key.  That will automatically also add an index to hid1.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Also, check the output of EXPLAIN.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html and related links.